# SQL выборка из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть две таблицы животные и комплекс, нужно провести выборку.

1. Определить суточное потребление корма обитателями комплекса 'приматы'.
2. Определить общую численность представителей семейства 'псовые' в зоопарке.
3. Вывести все пары видов, которые содержатся в одном помещении.

не понимаю как правильно их связать или же вывести, вводил sql Запрос чтоб сделать выборку 1
но вывело не приматов а полностью всех,
SELECT sum(суточное_потребление_корма) as приматыЕда24 FROM комплекс, животное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вторая таблица плохо нормализована, поэтому надо немного городить огород:

1.

```
SELECT sum(суточное_потребление_корма) as приматыЕда24
FROM животное
WHERE id_комплекса = (SELECT MIN(id_комплекса) FROM комплекс WHERE название_комплекса = "приматы")
```

Костыль с вложенным запросом - потому, что нет гарантии, что в таблице не окажется несколько разных id_комплекса с одинаковым названием "приматы".

2. По имеющимся данным даже я не могу это определить, не то, что MySQL :) В первой таблице мы можем, конечно, увидеть, где живут эти псовые, и посмотреть население соответствующих комплексов. Но никто не гарантирует, что в этих комплексах не живут представители других семейств, поэтому остаётся только гадать.
3. 

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT вид)
FROM животное
GROUP BY (id_комплекса, id_помещения)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT вид) > 1
```